# why first gets() function is not working?

Tags: c, function

Here first `gets()` is not working. if I add one more `gets()` function then from the two last one goes to work. how can I fix it?

**CODE**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{   
short int choice;
char number[15];

do{
printf("\n\nAnswer: ");
scanf("%hd",&choice);
printf("\n");
if(choice==1)
{
    printf("Enter the decimal number: ");
    gets(number);
}
else
{
    printf("Wrong input!.");
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}
}while(choice!=1);  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: never use `gets()`, use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the when the user pressed the enter key to give you the input for the `scanf` call, the enter key added a newline in the input buffer. And the `gets` call read that newline as an empty line.

One way to solve it is to use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read the first input too, and use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to parse it to a number:

```
...
printf("\n\nAnswer: ");

char input[64];
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
sscanf(input, "%hd", &choice);

printf("\n");
...
```

This make sure that the newline after the input is read and skipped.

Another way is to read one character at a time in a loop after the `scanf` call, until you have read the newline:

```
scanf("%hd", &choice);

int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
{
    // Empty
}
```

And a third way is to simply ask the `scanf` call to read and ignore white-space after the input:

```
scanf("%hd ", &choice);
//        ^
//        |
// Note space here
```

All of these methods have both pros and cons. You can try them all and use the one that works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I got it.

Comment: `scanf("%hd ",` is not a good idea (in an interactive application). It means that scanf call will block until the person enters a non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip the whitespace (i.e. the newline) following the number in the input buffer. This can be done by modifying the scanf to:

```
scanf("%hd ",&choice);
```

And use fgets(), since gets() is prone to buffer overflows.

Comment: `scanf("%hd ",` is not a good idea (in an interactive application). It means that scanf call will block until the person enters a non-whitespace character. The user will sit there wondering why pressing enter is having no effect.